# How Do I Test an API With Swift Concurrency

Tags: swift, xcode, concurrency, xctest, swift-concurrency

I'm trying to test an API I'm writing with Structured Concurrency. I prefer to run my tests with `continueAfterFailure = false` so that I may establish preconditions on my tests. At the moment my test is:

```
func testRssUrl() async throws {
    self.continueAfterFailure = false // 1
    let xml = PodcastXml.url(url)
    let feed = try await xml.feed // 2
    let rssFeed: RSSFeed? = feed.rssFeed
    XCTAssertNil(rssFeed) // 3 Included for this example
    XCTAssertNotNil(rssFeed) // 4
    validate(zebraFeed: rssFeed!) // 5
}
```

My expectation of Swift Concurrency is that the `try await` (2) should hold the method, until the expression resolves to a value or the expression throws. Either of the `XCTAssertNil` (3) or `XCTAssertNotNil` (4) should fail (in the actual test, I'm only using `XCTAssertNotNil`).

As written, between the two asserts and the try, `validate(zebraFeed:)` (5) should never be called because of `continueAfterFailure` (1).
Yet it is. The test still fails because `XCTAssertNil` (3) is failing, which is my actual expectation, but the test execution should also be stopping there.

What am I missing?

====Update======

Following replies I have an expanded example:

```
class TestAwaitTests: XCTestCase {

    struct Thing {
        let value = true
        func doSomething() async throws -> Int? {
            try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 5_000_000_000)
            return 1
        }
    }

    func validation(thing: Thing, file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
        XCTAssertFalse(thing.value)
        XCTAssertTrue(thing.value) // Breakpoint here
    }

    func testTest() async throws {
        continueAfterFailure = false
        let thing = Thing()
        let result = try await thing.doSomething()
        print("print 1")
        XCTAssertNil(result)
        print("print 2")
        XCTAssertNotNil(result)
        print("print 3")
        validation(thing: thing)
        enum Err: Error { case oops }
        throw Err.oops
        print("print 4")
    }
}
```

With console output:

```
print 1
print 2
print 3
```

The test fails, as expected.  What is unexpected is that the statements `print 2` and `print 3` are produced.  `continueAfterFailure` should be stopping the test first assertion.

===Update 2===

The second case had been updated with a `validate(thing:)` method. With `continueAfterFailure` set to false, the line marked `Breakpoint here` should never execute.

Comment: This seems like a bug, if the test method is `async` then `continueAfterFailure` has no effect for some reason.